# How do I upload JSON file to react web-app and get the link to the file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, flutter

How can I upload JSON file to my react app and get the link to the JSON file? My app dev is trying to do app linking and said that is what he needs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## What I would do

If only you need local access to the file, [Code Awesome's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70069876/15160478) will suffice. That method will **not** work if your app developer also needs to be able to visit the site, as the URL will only work for the client who uploaded the file.

Otherwise, using the information you've provided I'm going to give an example of what I would do using the following assumptions:

- You're using [create-react-app](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html)
- You aren't responsible for the backend of the site (if any)
- You're using [React Router](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start)

### Backend method

What you are describing is a backend operation. A central application which holds persistent data that various frontend applications can interact with. To get direct access to the file, you would need to send a HTTP request to the server with the JSON file, store the file in a media folder on the server, and provide the file to those who query it. Using the assumption that you don't have access to the backend, this method will not work.

### Static HTML Method

**NOTE**: If the user is the one uploading the JSON, or the JSON is dynamic and based on state, this **will not** work. This will only work if you are the one putting the file on the site, and the file is static. For dynamic/user uploads, again you would need a backend of some sort.

In your question, it says "How can I upload JSON...". I am therefore continuing with the assumption that it is you personally, and not a user uploading the file.

If the above doesn't apply, another approach which might suit your needs is to create a route using React Router (again, going off of the assumptions), such as:

```js
index.js
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```json
data.json
{"foo": "bar"}
```

```js
App.js
import * as React from "react";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

// If you're using create-react-app, json-loader comes
// pre-installed and allows imports of JSON
import data from "./data.json";

function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="json" element={<Json />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}

function Json() {
  return <>{JSON.stringify(data)}</>;
}

export default App;
```

When you start your site, and go to /json the following will be displayed:
[image: Picture of json data]

The app developer would then need to web scrape the site to access the JSON.

This satisfies your original request involving an approach involving a URL to the file, but if the file is static then you could just send it directly to the app developer without uploading it, which would be much easier and more efficient as web scraping is quite slow.

Answer (score 0):

### When received your JSON file, then display in browser

```js
const [ JsonFile, setJsonFile ] = useState({})

const uploadFile = (event)=>{
const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(){
    window.location.href = reader.result;
        }
reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
setJsonFile(event.target.files[0]);
}
```

### Get your JSON file from client

```js
<input type="file" onChange={uploadFile} />
```