# How to serve JSON file via React without NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, api, web-services

I am using React without NodeJS. I created it using

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

I want to serve a static JSON file or its content (I already have the file in the project) via a link so that it can be integrated by other software by calling this as API.

I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70070284/3701393) but the generated content is a webpage consists of HTML tags, but what I actually want is to return only either the JSON file or its data for people to request.

Comment: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/

Comment: @super I tried your suggested solution, using public folder. However, since I used the json files in src folder, now I have copied the files into the public folder and the client now is able to access the file from the public folder. The issue is that I now have to maintain 2 separate set of the same json files. One in src folder that is used in my code everywhere; the other is the copied ones in public folder. Is there anyway I can change it so that I can only point to one specific place either the src or the public folder for this to work?

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is to just copy the file to your `public` folder as part of the build-step. You can also access the file and it's contents in your app using the `%PUBLIC_URL%` syntax as described in the link.

Answer (score 1):

step 1 -just go to https://replit.com/ and sign up there... after signup you will have your dashboard there create a new repel and when it asks for template just choose the "NODE JS" option [image: like this] .

step 2- now just paste the below code in your index.js file.

DONT FORGET TO CHANGE YOUR FILE NAME AT LINE 3 from db.json to your file name.

```
const jsonServer = require('json-server');
const server = jsonServer.create();
const router = jsonServer.router('db.json');
const middlewares = jsonServer.defaults();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

server.use(middlewares);
server.use(router);

server.listen(port);
```

Step 3 - now there you will see a package .json file replace its code with the following code.

```
{
  "name": "jsonserver",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "��#\u0000 \u0000j\u0000s\u0000o\u0000n\u0000s\u0000e\u0000r\u0000v\u0000e\u0000r\u0000\r\u0000 \u0000",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/geekyvinayak/jsonserver.git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/geekyvinayak/jsonserver/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/geekyvinayak",
  "dependencies": {
    "json-server": "^0.17.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20"
  }
}
```

Step 4- now upload you json file. from upload file options present at left menu. BUt make sure that index.json line 3 code and your file number match.
[image]

step 5: Now just run the code from button at center top of website and in output box it will show outbut with url using which you can access the json file.

[image]

Comment: I have done this project using only React for static website for several months now. It did not have this requirement of having to serve JSON files or even APIs so I went for this design. However, this requirement is just come up with only this little feature for serving the file or an API for it. Therefore, I want to find a way that I do not have to involve an entire NodeJS with all of the server implementation just for this.

Comment: on which framework or library your server is made from which you want to send json file

Comment: I use React for this project and deploy it to Vercel (hobby) for hosting it. I want to serve a json file or its content via a link from that website.

Comment: great i can tell you how to host the json server for free there you can host the json file and from your react app you can send api requests for get post put and delete.. jus fetch the data and render it

Comment: I just want to serve it on this React project server.

Comment: yes you can like refer this link https://jsonserver.vinayak04.repl.co/users and you can fetch all you data

Comment: Then you can edit this answer to describe how to achieve the goal step-by-step. If it works for me, I will accept it.

Comment: @holydragon i have updated the answer refer to it and if you stuck somewhere do comment else dont forget to accept and upvote the answer.

Comment: That is still a solution for serving the file in different server, which is not what I am looking for.

Comment: but you can get your json data through this and as its a hobby project its also free. and that server never shuts down so...

Comment: Having it on another server causes another set of issues to me. I will have to update both JSON files in 2 servers whenever I need to update one, which is very often in this project. Moreover, it increases the complexity and decreases the maintainability of the project.